# How to convert a pandas series of integer timestamp to datetime (using fromtimestamp)? Error = cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a dataframe with timestamps in integer form. I would like to convert this to datetime, so I can plot the data using `mplfinance.plot()` (this gives the following error if I try to plot using the timestamps):

```
Expect data.index as DatetimeIndex
```

Below is a sample to show the problem:

```
import datetime as dt

data = {'timestamp':  [1364774700, 1364775000,1364775900]}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['timestamp'])

df['datetime'] = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(df['timestamp'])
```

but this produces the error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

Using fromtimestamp on a single timestamp value works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those integer timestamps are seconds since the Unix epoch ("Unix time"); use `pandas.to_datetime` with `unti=second` specified to convert `df['timestamp']` to a `DatetimeIndex`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': [1364774700, 1364775000, 1364775900]})

df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='s'))
#                       timestamp
# timestamp                      
# 2013-04-01 00:05:00  1364774700
# 2013-04-01 00:10:00  1364775000
# 2013-04-01 00:25:00  1364775900
```

Answer (score 0):

`df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])`

Should do the trick. My understanding is that pandas datetime and the datetime module are subtly different, and that when working with pandas you're better off using the pandas implementation.

Comment: pandas.to_datetime assumes nanosecond input by default if you supply a numeric value, so you'll have to specify the unit parameter.